# Selecting the first N rows of each group ordered by date

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by, master-detail, sql-limit

I'm trying to list the first N rows (100 first) ordered by DateTime grouping like Master Detail.

```
USE [Test]
Create Table [dbo].[Masters] (
    [MasterId] [nchar](36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Tags] [nchar](100) NULL,
    [Numbers] [int] NOT NULL
);

Create Table [dbo].[Details] (
    [DetailId] [nchar](36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [MasterId] [nchar](36) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Masters(MasterId),
    [Date_Time] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO Masters (MasterId, Tags, Numbers) VALUES ('M0', 'Tag0,Tag1', 6);
INSERT INTO Masters (MasterId, Tags, Numbers) VALUES ('M1', 'Tag1,Tag2', 5);
INSERT INTO Masters (MasterId, Tags, Numbers) VALUES ('M2', 'Tag0,Tag2', 6);

INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D0', 'M0', '20190101 00:00:00 AM', 0);
INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D1', 'M0', '20200101 11:00:00 AM', 1);
INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D2', 'M0', '20200701 01:00:00 AM', 2);
INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D3', 'M0', '20210715 10:00:00 AM', 3);
INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D4', 'M0', '20210715 11:00:00 AM', 4);
INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D5', 'M0', '20210715 11:00:00 AM', 5);

INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D10', 'M1', '20190101 00:00:00 AM', 6);
INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D11', 'M1', '20200101 01:00:00 AM', 7);
INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D12', 'M1', '20200701 09:00:00 AM', 8);
INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D13', 'M1', '20210101 10:00:00 AM', 9);
INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D14', 'M1', '20210701 10:00:00 AM', 10);

INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D20', 'M2', '20190101 00:00:00 AM', 11);
INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D21', 'M2', '20190101 01:30:00 AM', 12);
INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D22', 'M2', '20200101 01:30:00 AM', 13);
INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D23', 'M2', '20200701 08:30:00 AM', 14);
INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D24', 'M2', '20210101 01:30:00 AM', 15);
INSERT INTO Details (DetailId, MasterId, Date_Time, Value) VALUES ('D25', 'M2', '20210701 01:30:00 AM', 16);

Select * from Masters;
Select * from Details;
--
```

[image]

Now my partial query:

```
SELECT m.MasterId, d.DetailId, m.Numbers, d.Date_Time, d.Value from Details AS d
INNER JOIN Masters AS m ON m.MasterId = d.MasterId
WHERE 
m.Tags LIKE '%Tag2%' AND 
d.Date_Time >= Convert(datetime, '2020-01-01' ) 
ORDER BY m.MasterId DESC, d.Date_Time;
```

But, **How introduce `Top 3` (really maybe 50 or 100 in the real situation) for my query in this example?** I would like to obtain only **3** rows per `MasterId`.

[image]

According to the image we will get only six rows.
Please help me to fix my query.

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the `row_number` solution, another option is `CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP`:

```sql
SELECT m.masterid,
       d.detailid,
       m.numbers,
       d.date_time,
       d.value
    FROM masters AS m
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP (3) *
        FROM details AS d
        WHERE d.date_time >= '2020-01-01'
        AND m.masterid = d.masterid
    ) AS d
    WHERE m.tags LIKE '%Tag2%'
    ORDER BY m.masterid DESC,
             d.date_time;
```

This may be faster or slower than `row_number`, mostly depending on cardinalities (quantity of rows) and indexing.

If indexing is good and it's a small number of rows it will usually be faster. If the inner table needs sorting or you are anyway selecting most rows then use `row_number`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `row_number()` window function here.

```
SELECT x.masterid,
       x.detailid,
       x.numbers,
       x.date_time,
       x.value
       FROM (SELECT m.masterid,
                    d.detailid,
                    m.numbers,
                    d.date_time,
                    d.value,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY m.masterid
                                       ORDER BY d.date_time ASC) AS rn
                    FROM details AS d
                         INNER JOIN masters AS m
                                    ON m.masterid = d.masterid
                    WHERE m.tags LIKE '%Tag2%'
                          AND d.date_time >= '2020-01-01') AS x
       WHERE x.rn <= 3 -- change to whatever your n is
       ORDER BY x.masterid DESC,
                x.date_time ASC;
```